# soffit to attic access on gable end?

Tags: framing, attic

I want to install a camera/flood light under the soffit on the gable end of the house. Note the location of red arrow in below pic. After I take off the aluminum soffit cover, will I have access to the attic?

I'm thinking under the aluminum soffit will be hollow, then maybe plywood on the wall side that I would drill through to access attic?

I need to run a 14/2 wire to the location of the floodlight. The nearby soffit light wont' work, it's on a switch and I want the flood light to always have power.

[image: flood light location]
[image: under side of soffit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're on a gable end hit wall sheathing and sheathing on the gable end truss, depending on height. You'll want to try and drill through the sheathing as high as possible to get above the wall plates and truss bottom chord. You can drill through the truss if necessary.

Your best bet might be to route the cable around to the overhead door wall, where you'll find open bays between the trusses. There may be insulation baffles, but you'll have a relatively clear route.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I guess the only disadvantage to teh overhead door wall is that I'd have to remove more aluminum soffit covering. I'm hoping the soffit panels aren't nailed on the wall side.

Comment: Typically they're only nailed at the fascia and simply inserted into the F-channel at the wall.